# Symfony2 Form Submission with Complex Entites

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an `Article` entity which has several many to many and many to one relations. Accordingly I also created a complex `FormType` for the entity. My main goal is use following for the process of entity validation, as I am trying to implement a RESTful API:

```
$form->submit(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));
```

Everything looks fine, but the request data is having array of parameters but form submit looks for object type while setting child entities and it leads to

> Expected argument of type "MyProject\Entity\Author", "array" given

Any clue or help would be great.

Comment: Please, would show the Form Type code to more verbose ? However,  the submitted data should be a `string` or `array` perfectly.

Comment: Which Symfony version are you using ? For > 2.5 you should use `$form->handleRequest($request);` nothing else.